# How can i get coefficients of filter in matlab

Tags: matlab, filter

I designed band-pass filter 'elliptic'  using design function in matlab, how can i get the coefficients of this filter [A, B]. I see Hd file in workspace containing some files(scalevalus, states sosMatrix).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `coeffs` of the DSP System Toolbox:

```
s = coeffs(Hd);
s.Numerator
```

EDIT:
You are actually using cascaded second order filters, so it is not defined with numerator B and denominator A, but the coefficients of the cascaded sections are in the Hd.sosMatrix:

[fvtool](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/fvtool.html):

> sos is a K-by-6 matrix, where the number of sections, K, must be greater than or equal to 2. If the number of sections is less than 2, fvtool considers the input to be a numerator vector. Each row of sos corresponds to the coefficients of a second order (biquad) filter. The ith row of the sos matrix corresponds to [bi(1) bi(2) bi(3) ai(1) ai(2) ai(3)].

So if you really need an equivalent classic filter with coefficients [A,B] your best option is to use sos2tf, but this is only an approximation:

```
[B,A] = sos2tf(Hd.sosMatrix,Hd.ScaleValues);
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, i have already used it but it gives me the same  files (scalevalus, states sosMatrix). i want to find [A, B].

Comment: Can you post the exact code you used to create the filter.

Comment: h  = fdesign.bandpass(Fstop1, Fpass1, Fpass2, Fstop2, Astop1, Apass, ...
                      Astop2, Fs);
Hd = design(h, 'ellip')